# Inaccessible rawurlencoded UTF-8 URL

Tags: apache, url, utf-8, urlencode, url-encoding

I have a shared hosting account and I am using Filezilla to connect to the server.

Under the `public_html/items/` folder, there are many subfolders and their folder names are encoded using PHP `rawurlencode` function, like these:

```
apple
banana
orange
%E6%BC%A2%E5%A0%A1%E9%A3%BD
%E8%96%AF%E6%A2%9D
```

The problem is that I get 404 error when I access the files under the folders whose names contain non-ASCII characters (e.g. chinese characters).

This means I can access URL like this one:
http://my-domain.com/items/apple/index.html

But not:
http://my-domain.com/items/%E6%BC%A2%E5%A0%A1%E9%A3%BD/index.html

What kind of a problem could this possibly be?

Many thanks to you all.

Comment: I think you'll have to urlencode the string twice. At the moment, the characters will be decoded and the decoded result will be searched for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the folders contain physically urlencoded names, then you'll need to ensure these names are themselves urlencoded in your urls. In fact, anytime you create a URL from any 'uncontrolled', potentially url-unsafe elements, you must urlencode those elements.

Thus if you have a directory named `%E8%96%AF%E6%A2%9D`

You would refer to it in a URL with `%25E8%2596%25AF%25E6%25A2%259D`

Pretty, isn't it?

Another way of looking at this is that when you use your existing urlencoded URL, what the server actually tries to resolve is /items/漢堡飽/index.html